# A riddle that is first of its kind

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My first, yet simple, puzzle on this site.

> By myself, I’m as light as can be
>
> But throw me a ball, and suddenly I’ll be heavy
>
> Give me another, and I’ll get quite excited
>
> Because shortly thereafter, I will become a he instead.

What am I?

Comment: The title needs to be more specific.

Comment: @PeterMortensen My intention was to make the title have a very obvious clue.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but $\ast$ (ROT13) jura lbh fnvq "ur", V qvqa'g guvax bs n znyr; V gubhtug bs "Ur" nf va "Uryvhz", naq gur "rkpvgrq" cneg znqr zr n yvggyr zber vagrerfgrq. V gura terj rkpvgrq zlfrys, hagvy V fnj @EnaqNyGube'f nafjre... V guvax guvf cneg jnf gur ovt tvirnjnl, naq abg gur gvgyr. Ohg V yvxr culfvpf... $\ast$ Great puzzle, nonetheless! I have reached my daily voting limit and have to wait $9$ hours before I can vote again (DVL9), so I have favourited instead $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the original title, just FTR. It's part of the nature of [Puzzling.se] that we have a lot of puzzles with 'unspecific' titles.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't mind the titles in a puzzle. I usually ignore them and then once I believe I have solved the answer, I explain the title last. (Even when I make my own riddles/puzzles, I leave the title 'til last.) :P

Comment: @user477343 Thanks! As a newbie, can I ask if this would be the type of puzzle that is appropriate to put "What/Who am I" to make it less obvious, or did that not factor in at all?

Comment: Yeah, sure! Go for it. I mean, what/who's stopping you? :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you

> a hydrogen atom/nucleus?

*By myself, I’m as light as can be*

> Hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table. Specifically, this would refer to the standard isotope of **protium**, with just a single proton in the nucleus.

*But throw me a ball, and suddenly I’ll be heavy*

> **Deuterium**, a hydrogen isotope with one proton and one neutron, is called heavy water.

*Give me another, and I’ll get quite excited*

> **Tritium**, a hydrogen isotope with one proton and two neutrons, is in an excited state ...

*Because shortly thereafter, I will become a he instead.*

> ... and soon decays into **helium**-3, denoted by "He" on the periodic table.

---

**Feedback section**

I think the word "excited" was the first key for me in solving this. That word seems likely to have a non-obvious meaning that fits the context of whatever the solution is, and the only second meaning I could think of was in physics. From the first line I guessed the answer might be a photon, so I spent a while barking up that tree and thinking about particle interactions involving photons on Feynman diagrams. Then I realised what the "he" must mean, and from there it was easy to construct the right answer after a quick look at a list of isotopes on Wikipedia.

Comment: I see we have similar lines of thinking.

Comment: Apparently too easy.. You guys sure are fast!

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I had to think for a minute to be sure, but I think I *just* beat you to it :-) Have a +1.

Comment: You're right, of course. I think it was 45 seconds or so.

Comment: Hey T James, I know it's not what you intended, but I think my answer might fit the clues better.

Comment: darn it! I was 20 seconds behind. I got the full explanation in though!

Comment: @TJames Nice riddle! Feedback section added.

Comment: @jwi You get my +1 as well :-)

Comment: @flashstorm Sorry, but I think this answer fits better if you consider the wordplay. The words "heavy", "excited", and "he" are *all* confirming this answer.

Comment: I should add that you are the only one who truly got the heavy reference correct. Impressive in such a short amount of time.

Answer (score 6):

Are you:

> Hydrogen (nucleus)

By myself, I’m as light as can be

> Lowest atomic weight from all the elements

But throw me a ball, and suddenly I’ll be heavy

> Add an electron, atomic weight increases

Give me another, and I’ll get quite excited

> Add more electrons or even a proton+neutron, it will go through chemical change

Because shortly thereafter, I will become a he instead.

> From that, it becomes He, helium

Comment: Really close, but missed the heavy reference just a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You are an

> electron

By myself, I’m as light as can be

> Electrons have essentially as little mass as possible without being massless

But throw me a ball, and suddenly I’ll be heavy

> the ball is a proton (or a proton-neutron pair)

Give me another, and I’ll get quite excited

> Then you will be a helium ion

Because shortly thereafter, I will become a he instead.

> helium ions are so good at stabilizing that it will pull an electron from somewhere and become stable. He is the atomic symbol for helium

Comment: Not exactly what I was thinking, but I am impressed that you actually came up with an alternate answer for what I thought was a rather specific riddle. +1!

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Hydrogen?

By myself, I’m as light as can be

> Hydrogen is the lightest element.

But throw me a ball, and suddenly I’ll be heavy

> I believe this is referring to adding a neutron to the hydrogen atom. It'll make tritium, which makes it nearly twice as heavy.

Give me another, and I’ll get quite excited

> Radioactive isotope.

Because shortly thereafter, I will become a he instead.

> Turns into helium.